# Clojurescript — PersistentArrayMap → Object → PersistentArrayMap — transferring data between web worker

Tags: clojurescript, web-worker, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to pass a clojurescript map to a webworker.
Before I pass it, it is of type `PersistentArrayMap`.

```
cljs.core.PersistentArrayMap {meta: null, cnt: 3, arr: Array(6), __hash: null, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$: 16647951…}
```

However, when it gets to the worker, it's just a plain old Object

```
Object {meta: null, cnt: 3, arr: Array(6), __hash: null, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$: 16647951…}
```

with the data seemingly intact. At this point I'd like to turn it back into a `PersistentArrayMap` so that I can work with it in cljs again.

Using `clj->js` and `js->clj` doesn't really work because it doesn't distinguish between keywords and strings, so some data is lost.

What's the best way to handle this situation? It's possible that I'm going about this in the entirely wrong way.

Comment: Do you mind using [transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-cljs)? It preserves the type of a persistent array map.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in solution is to serialize the data to EDN and reading it back. `clj->js` is inherently lossy and should be avoided.

You start by turning the object into a string and send that over to the worker.

```
(pr-str {:a 1})
;; => "{:a 1}"
```

In the worker you read it back via `cljs.reader/read-string`

```
(cljs.reader/read-string "{:a 1}")
;; => {:a 1}
```

This will usually be good enough but the `transit-cljs` library will be slightly faster. Depending on the amount of data you plan on sending it may be worth the extra dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `keywordize-keys` in the code?

```
(def json "{\"foo\": 1, \"bar\": 2, \"baz\": [1,2,3]}")
(def a (.parse js/JSON json))
;;=> #js {:foo 1, :bar 2, :baz #js [1 2 3]}

(js->clj a)
;;=> {"foo" 1, "bar" 2, "baz" [1 2 3]}

(js->clj a :keywordize-keys true)
;;=> {:foo 1, :bar 2, :baz [1 2 3]}
```

Full documentation [is here](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/js-GTclj).

Comment: I did try `:keywordize-keys`, but i only works for map keys. Keywords in e.g. arrays are still a problem.

    {:foo [:bar :bazz]} => {"foo": ["bar", "bazz"]} => {:foo ["bar" "bazz"]}